# Question not appearing in my profile

Tags: support, questions, user-profiles

Last night I wanted to check a question I posted to see if it got any answers or comments (yes, I'm aware of the "inbox" function; I just wanted to make sure) but I couldn't find the question. I tried searching for it and looking in my profile, but I couldn't find it. At first I thought maybe a moderator had removed it, but I don't know of any reason why that would happen, and besides, I probably would have received a message with an explanation if that was the case. Today, I got back on the computer I used to submit the question and opened it from my history, and it was still there, but it's still not in my profile. What's wrong?

**Question in question**: (no pun intended) ["Access is denied" when editing Windows Store app files even after taking ownership](https://superuser.com/questions/714621/access-is-denied-when-editing-windows-store-app-files-even-after-taking-owners)

Comment: View more: http://superuser.com/users/77056/flarn2006?tab=questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can still see it.

[image]

Are you sure you've set the filter to newest rather than votes?

Comment: Yep; that was the problem. Thanks! :-)